# Block user using ip and cookies using .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, web

can any one help me create a block rule to block a user on the basis of ip,cookie value and visited URL as inputs to .htaccess file.

Few points:

1. User should be blocked,only from certain directories on website not
   entire site
2. Blocked user should be redirected to a specified URL.
3. BlockRule need not to set cookies as cookies already exist in user browser,block rule only have to read existing cookie value,match it with one in block rule and do the redirection.

**Edit :** jon answered my above query,
but i also want to **log these IP(%{REMOTE_ADDR})/cookie values(%{HTTP_COOKIE})** from .htaccess file into some file on server.

Answer (score 1):

You can combing all of these conditions into a single rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

# by IP
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123.45.67.89$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123.45.67.88$
```

So do something if either the IP is 123.45.67.89 or 123.45.67.88.

```
# By cookie
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} foo=bar; [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !something
```

So do something if ether there's a cookie called **foo** with the value **bar**, or if there *is no cookie named **something***.

```
# by request
RewriteRule ^/?(bad_url|should/not/have/access|my_images) /blocked.html [L,R]
```

So if all the above conditions are met, and the request is made for `/bad_url`, `/should/not/have/access`, or `/my_images`, then the browser gets redirected to `/blocked.html`

Comment: Can you please also answer my Edit.The solution you have given and the way you have explained has helped me a lot.

Comment: @David That's completely unrelated, look into the `CustomLog` directive, it's not something you can do with htaccess